# The Component 'ToolBarComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, deployment

I am trying to deploy an app using netlify, but the deploys are failing with the following error:

```
 Error: src/app/components/toolbar/toolbar.component.ts:12:14 - error NG6007: The Component 'ToolBarComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.
```

The problem is that I am using the declaration statement to use it in other pages like that:

```
 18   declarations: [DestinyPage, ToolBarComponent, ModalDestinyPage],
```

I tried to use it in the import statement but it failed with the error:

```
ToolBarComponent does not have 'ɵmod' property
```

I tried to use the export statement as well and got the same error, another solution that I saw here in the stack was to use the module instead of the component in the files that use the toolbar, but the toolbar doesn't have a page, so I think it was no applicable.

Can someone help me?

git link: https://github.com/devpupo/baps-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the following command you will get the error locally: ng build --prod

Since you are using the toolbar component in multiple modules, I would advise moving the component into a SharedModule and instead of importing the component into multiple modules, you need to import that module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolBarComponent} from '../components/toolbar/toolbar.component';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
  ToolBarComponent,
],
exports: [
  ToolBarComponent,
]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Then you will need to import the SharedModule into the other module you will use.

```
import { SharedModule} from '../example.module';
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   SharedModule
 ]
   ...
  })
```

I can see that the toolbar component is called in all other components, if you are trying to do a header/footer for a page (a component that will be displayed for whatever the route or component), consider using router outlet as well - `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` where you can call the toolbar component in a parent component and only once without affecting the other modules/component.

Sharing module:
https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules
Router Outlet:
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Comment: I did this shared module and got a new error:
core.js:14841 NG0304: 'ion-tabs' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-tabs' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-tabs' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

I did some research and all that I found it was about ion-tab instead of ion-tabs

Comment: It was missing some imports in the shared module, but now it's working, thanks!!